# regular typeface for numbers inside example env

Tags: typography

Consider the following code and output

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\begin{example} 1,2,3 \end{example}

\begin{example} $1$,$2$,$3$ \end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I find the second version more attractive. Is there a way to get it without having to put every number into math mode? In other words, is there code that can be added to example to make it automatic?

Comment: Since you're using `amsbook`, you have the facilities of `amsthm` available.  I suspect that the text of an exercise would be better set upright, not italic, so a different theorem style would be appropriate.  Before `\newtheorem{example}` add `\theoremstyle{definition}` to get upright text.  By the way, `amsmath` is already included in `amsbook`, so you needn't load it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll clear the clutter.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want `upshape` font, don't care whether it is math font or text font. You can use `\theoremstyle{definition}`. And in `amsbook`, math font is also Computer Modern, the number in math or text is same. You will not see the difference.

```latex
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\begin{example} 1,2,3 \end{example}

\begin{example} $1$,$2$,$3$ \end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]